# Simple option handling using Boost library (C++)

Tags: c++, boost

For instance, using the following syntax:

```
 -I [file] -A 1 2 3
```

Question:

How to check if a **file** was specified and additionally if **three** (integer) values were specified.

I understand the following:

```
po::options_descriptions desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
```

How to then use the specified arguments, for instance:

```
    if (argv[3] == 1) {
        ...
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the `variables_map` to check whether options were specified. If you added an option called `"file"` and your `variables_map` was called `vm`:

```
if(vm.count("myoption")) { ... } // Returns 0 if myoption not specified. 1 or more if it was.
```

Once you've used `add_options` to add some options, you can access them like so, assuming that you've setup a `variables_map` named `vm`:

```
vm["myoption"].as<int>() // Will return an int, assuming your option is an int
vm["myoption"].as<std::string>() // Will return an std::string, assuming your option is an int
```

In your case, you want to convert one of the specified options to a sequence of integers. You can do that like so:

```
vm["myoption"].as< std::vector<int> >()
```

Which will return a vector containing the 3 integers, which you can index and use just like any normal vector. To see if there are specifically 3, just use the `size()` vector member function.

The boost tutorial on this is located [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html).